# get handle in thread function

Tags: c, windows, winapi

whole code download: http://tunps.com/tmp/UsbAutoCopy.zip
[image: program screen shot]

here is the WinMain :

```
int APIENTRY WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                      LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{
        DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAIN),
                  hWnd, DlgProc);

  return 0;
}
```

in global scope:

```
typedef struct ArgsTag {
    CHAR vol;
    HWND hWndDlg;
} Args, *pArgs;
```

in Message loop:

```
pArgs arg;
arg = malloc(sizeof(struct ArgsTag));
arg->vol= FirstDriveFromMask(lpdbv->dbcv_unitmask);
arg->hWndDlg = hWndDlg;
_beginthread ((LPVOID)CopyThread, 0, (LPVOID)arg) ;
```

here is the Dialog procedure function prototype:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hWndDlg, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

get the right `arg->vol` but `arg->hWndDlg` return the wrong address.

**in CopyThread thread, i wanna get the main window handle (`hWndDlg`).**

```
hLog = GetDlgItem(arg->hWndDlg,IDC_LOG);
```

after google alot, i still find nothing, so how do i get the right hWndDlg child HWND ?

by the way, the size information

`sizeof(args)` = 4

`sizeof(ArgsTag)` = 8

`sizeof(args->vol)` = 1

`sizeof(args->hWndDlg)` = 4

update:2011.07.01

OK, i am insanely mad now on this question.

i would like to post the whole code this, compiles on **visual c++ 6.0 / win32 application**

It's a usb auto-copy programs, It can detect USB storage device plugged in and copy the designated file path on the USB storage device to the designated directory on hard disk and while show logs on right edit box of the programs.

**uac.c**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dbt.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include "resource.h"
#include "Shlwapi.h"

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define _TRACE true;
DEV_BROADCAST_HDR* dhr;
PDEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME lpdbv;
//OPENFILENAME ofn;
BROWSEINFO bi;
LPITEMIDLIST lpItemIdList;
HWND hWnd;
static HICON hIcon,hIconSm;
HANDLE hFile,hFileList,hDstDir,hLog,hBtnSave,hBtnBrowse;
DWORD err,dwWritenSize = 0;
CHAR vol,bufFileList[1024],bufDstDir[MAX_PATH],subStr[1024],buf[1024],buf2[1024],deviceID[1024];
TCHAR szPath[_MAX_PATH];
PCHAR pvol;
LPCTSTR configFileName = "D:\\win32dev\\sdk\\UsbAutoCopy\\Debug\\config.ini";
//LPSTR szPath;
UINT i,len,j=0;k=0;
FILE *stream;
char buflist[1000][1024]={0};
typedef struct ArgsTag {
    HWND hWndDlg;
    CHAR vol;    
} Args, *pArgs;
LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
LPTSTR ReadConfigFile(LPTSTR key);
BOOL WriteConfigFile(TCHAR *bufFileList,TCHAR *bufDstDir);
int ReplaceStr(char *sSrc, char *sMatchStr, char *sReplaceStr);
char FirstDriveFromMask (ULONG unitmask); //prototype
void CopyThread(CHAR vol);
char* getFileName(char* dirName);
/************************************************************************/
/* e.g: \1.txt->\1.txt      \dir1\dir2\test.exe->\test.exe              */
/************************************************************************/
char* getFileName(char* dirName)
{

    unsigned int i,j=0;
    //buf={0};
    for(i=strlen(dirName);i>=0;i--)
    {
        //fileName[j++] = dirName[i];
        if(dirName[i] == '\\')
        {
            for(j=0;j<strlen(dirName);)
                buf[j++] = dirName[i++];
            break;
        }
    }
    return buf;
}
void CopyThread(pArgs arg)
{
    char temp[1024];
    pvol = &(arg->vol);
    pvol[1] = 0;
    //GetPrivateProfileString("config","DeviceID","",buf,sizeof(buf),strcat(pvol,":\\dp\\device.ini")); 没有section无法读取DeviceID
    strcat(pvol,":\\dp\\device.ini");
    //hFile = CreateFile(pvol,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_WRITE,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
    //ReadFile((HANDLE)hFile,buf,sizeof(buf)/2,&dwWritenSize,NULL);

    // get the Device ID
   if( (stream = fopen( pvol, "r" )) != NULL )
   {
       while(fgets( buf, sizeof(buf), stream ))
       {
           if(i=strstr(buf,"DeviceID=") != NULL)
           {
               sscanf( buf, "DeviceID=%s",deviceID);
               break;
           }
       }
       fclose( stream );
       //make dir named with DeivceID
       GetWindowText(hFileList,bufFileList,sizeof(bufFileList)/sizeof(TCHAR));
       GetWindowText(hDstDir,bufDstDir,sizeof(bufDstDir)/sizeof(TCHAR));
       strcpy(temp,bufDstDir);
       strcat(temp,"\\");
       CreateDirectory(strcat(temp,deviceID),NULL);
       //started to copy and show log
        len = strlen(bufFileList);
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            buflist[j][k++] =  bufFileList[i];
            if(bufFileList[i] == '\n')
            {   
                k--;
                buflist[j][k] =0;
                buflist[j][--k] =0;
                j++;
                k=0;
            }
        }
       for(j=0;buflist[j][0] != 0;j++)
       {
            pvol = &(arg->vol);
            pvol[1] = 0;
            strcat(pvol,":");
            strcat(pvol,buflist[j]);
            strcpy(temp,bufDstDir);
            strcat(temp,"\\");
            strcat(temp,deviceID);
            CopyFile(pvol,strcat(temp,getFileName(buflist[j])),FALSE);
            //set log
            hLog = GetDlgItem(arg->hWndDlg,IDC_LOG);
            GetWindowText(hLog,buf2,sizeof(buf2));
            wsprintf(subStr,"#复制文件【】到【】...\r\n");
            strcat(buf2,subStr);
            SetWindowText(hLog,buf2);
       }

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,NULL,"无法打开Device.ini文件",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
}
// 替换字符串中特征字符串为指定字符串
int ReplaceStr(char *sSrc, char *sMatchStr, char *sReplaceStr)
{
    int  StringLen;
    char caNewString[1024];

    char *FindPos = strstr(sSrc, sMatchStr);
    if( (!FindPos) || (!sMatchStr) )
        return -1;

    while( FindPos )
    {
        memset(caNewString, 0, sizeof(caNewString));
        StringLen = FindPos - sSrc;
        strncpy(caNewString, sSrc, StringLen);
        strcat(caNewString, sReplaceStr);
        strcat(caNewString, FindPos + strlen(sMatchStr));
        strcpy(sSrc, caNewString);

        FindPos = strstr(sSrc, sMatchStr);
    }

    return 0;
}
LPTSTR ReadConfigFile(LPTSTR key)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(configFileName,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_WRITE,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
    err=GetLastError();
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    if(err == 2) // file not exists
    {
        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(configFileName,GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_WRITE,NULL,CREATE_NEW,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
//      err=GetLastError();
//      sprintf(buf,"%d",err);
//      MessageBox(NULL,buf,NULL,0);
    }
    else
    {
        //load config to app
        GetPrivateProfileString("config","filelist","",bufFileList,sizeof(bufFileList),configFileName);
        GetPrivateProfileString("config","dstdir","",bufDstDir,sizeof(bufDstDir),configFileName);
        ReplaceStr(bufFileList,";","\r\n");
        if(strcmp(key,"filelist") == 0)
            return bufFileList;
        if(strcmp(key,"dstdir") == 0)
            return bufDstDir;
    }
    return NULL;
}
BOOL WriteConfigFile(TCHAR *bufFileList,TCHAR *bufDstDir)
{
    ReplaceStr(bufFileList,"\r\n",";");
    i=WritePrivateProfileString("config","filelist",bufFileList,configFileName);
    WritePrivateProfileString("config","dstdir",bufDstDir,configFileName);
    return TRUE;
}
/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 FirstDriveFromMask (unitmask)

 Description
  Finds the first valid drive letter from a mask of drive letters.
  The mask must be in the format bit 0 = A, bit 1 = B, bit 2 = C, 
  and so on. A valid drive letter is defined when the 
  corresponding bit is set to 1.

 Returns the first drive letter that was found.
--------------------------------------------------------------------*/

char FirstDriveFromMask (ULONG unitmask)
{
 char i;

 for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
 {
  if (unitmask & 0x1)
   break;
  unitmask = unitmask >> 1;
 }

 return (i + 'A');
}
int APIENTRY WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                      LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{
        DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAIN),
                  hWnd, DlgProc);

  return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hWndDlg, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    hFileList = GetDlgItem(hWndDlg,IDC_FILE_LIST);
    hDstDir = GetDlgItem(hWndDlg,IDC_DST_DIR);
    hLog = GetDlgItem(hWndDlg,IDC_LOG);
    hBtnSave = GetDlgItem(hWndDlg,IDC_BTN_SAVE);
    hBtnBrowse = GetDlgItem(hWndDlg,IDC_BTN_BROWSE);
    switch(Msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        //icon setting
        hIcon = (HICON)LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL),MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON4));
        SendMessage(hWndDlg, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG  , (LPARAM)hIcon);
        hIconSm = (HICON)LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON4));
        SendMessage(hWndDlg, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)hIconSm);
        //read config file , if not exist, create a new one
        SetWindowText(hFileList,ReadConfigFile("filelist"));
        SetWindowText(hDstDir,ReadConfigFile("dstdir"));
        SetWindowText(hLog,"#等待设备...\r\n");
        return TRUE;

    case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
        dhr   =   (DEV_BROADCAST_HDR   *)lParam;
        switch(wParam)
        {
        case DBT_CONFIGCHANGECANCELED:
            return 0;
        case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
            if(dhr->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME)
            {
                lpdbv = (PDEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)dhr;
                if(lpdbv->dbcv_flags  == 0)
                {
                    //sprintf(buf,"%c",FirstDriveFromMask(lpdbv->dbcv_unitmask));
                    pArgs arg;
                    arg = malloc(sizeof(struct ArgsTag));
                    GetWindowText(hLog,buf2,sizeof(buf2));
                    arg->vol= FirstDriveFromMask(lpdbv->dbcv_unitmask);
                    arg->hWndDlg = hWndDlg;
                    wsprintf(subStr,"#检测盘符...【%c】盘\r\n",arg->vol);
                    strcat(buf2,subStr);
                    SetWindowText(hLog,buf2);
                    Sleep(1000);
                    //UsbCopyFile(ReadConfigFile("filelist"),ReadConfigFile("dstdir"), vol);
                    _beginthread ((LPVOID)CopyThread, 0, (LPVOID)arg) ;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
            case IDC_FILE_LIST:
                if(HIWORD(wParam) == EN_CHANGE)
                {
                    EnableWindow(hBtnSave,TRUE);
                }
                return TRUE;
            case IDC_DST_DIR:
                if(HIWORD(wParam) == EN_CHANGE)
                {
                    EnableWindow(hBtnSave,TRUE);
                }
                return TRUE;
            case IDCANCEL:
                EndDialog(hWndDlg, 0);
                return TRUE;
            case IDC_BTN_SAVE:
                //content of file list
                /*
                i = HIWORD(wParam);
                i = LOWORD(wParam);
                i = lParam;
                */
                GetWindowText(hFileList,bufFileList,sizeof(bufFileList)/sizeof(TCHAR));
                GetWindowText(hDstDir,bufDstDir,sizeof(bufDstDir)/sizeof(TCHAR));
                //write config
                WriteConfigFile(bufFileList,bufDstDir);
                EnableWindow(hBtnSave,FALSE);
                return TRUE;
            case IDC_BTN_BROWSE:
                //ZeroMemory(szPath, sizeof(szPath));
                ZeroMemory(&bi,sizeof(BROWSEINFO));
                bi.hwndOwner    = NULL;                          //HWND句柄
                bi.pidlRoot       = NULL;                          //默认值为NULL
                bi.lpszTitle       = ("文件浏览对话框");          //对话框标题
                bi.pszDisplayName = szPath;                          //选择文件夹路径
                bi.ulFlags        = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS;       //标记
                bi.lpfn           = NULL;                          //默认值为NULL
                bi.lParam         = 0;                          //回调消息
                lpItemIdList = SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);  //显示文件浏览对话框
                if(SHGetPathFromIDList(lpItemIdList,szPath))
                    SetWindowText(hDstDir,szPath);
                return TRUE;

            }
            break;
    }//end of Msg
    return FALSE;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**resource.h**

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Developer Studio generated include file.
// Used by UsbAutoCopy.rc
//
#define IDD_MAIN                        101
#define IDI_ICON1                       102
#define IDI_ICON2                       103
#define IDI_ICON3                       104
#define IDI_ICON4                       110
#define IDC_EDIT1                       1000
#define IDC_FILE_LIST                   1000
#define IDC_EDIT2                       1001
#define IDC_LOG                         1001
#define IDC_EDIT3                       1002
#define IDC_DST_DIR                     1002
#define IDC_BUTTON1                     1003
#define IDC_BTN_BROWSE                  1003
#define IDC_BUTTON2                     1004
#define IDC_BTN_SAVE                    1004

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        111
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         40002
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1005
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

**UsbAutoCopy.rc** : the resource script

```
//Microsoft Developer Studio generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "afxres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Chinese (P.R.C.) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_CHS)
#ifdef _WIN32
LANGUAGE LANG_CHINESE, SUBLANG_CHINESE_SIMPLIFIED
#pragma code_page(936)
#endif //_WIN32

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE DISCARDABLE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE DISCARDABLE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE DISCARDABLE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_MAIN DIALOG DISCARDABLE  200, 150, 449, 271
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | 
    WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "USB AutoCopy"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    GROUPBOX        "设置",IDC_STATIC,8,8,181,255
    GROUPBOX        "日志",IDC_STATIC,201,8,240,255
    EDITTEXT        IDC_FILE_LIST,18,37,160,134,ES_MULTILINE | 
                    ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_WANTRETURN | NOT WS_BORDER
    EDITTEXT        IDC_LOG,213,25,220,227,ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | 
                    ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_WANTRETURN | NOT WS_BORDER | 
                    WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL
    EDITTEXT        IDC_DST_DIR,18,198,110,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY
    PUSHBUTTON      "浏览",IDC_BTN_BROWSE,128,198,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "保存设置",IDC_BTN_SAVE,21,234,147,20
    CONTROL         "文件列表",IDC_STATIC,"Static",SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP | 
                    WS_GROUP,18,25,160,8
    LTEXT           "复制到目录",IDC_STATIC,18,185,110,8
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO DISCARDABLE 
BEGIN
    IDD_MAIN, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 8
        RIGHTMARGIN, 441
        TOPMARGIN, 8
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 263
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Icon
//

// Icon with lowest ID value placed first to ensure application icon
// remains consistent on all systems.
IDI_ICON4               ICON    DISCARDABLE     "Device-USB.ico"
#endif    // Chinese (P.R.C.) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

Comment: Are you calling `GetDlgItem` in the same thread from which the window was created?

Comment: Just wondering - you typedef _struct args*_ as _args_. So in order to create an instance of the struct, you must use _struct args_ as opposed to just _args_. Is this what your doing? Since _vol_ is the first member, its address is the address of the struct. using bad casts you might be treating a pointer as the struct itself, without really having the second part of the struct (_hWndDlg_).

Comment: @David Heffernan , i call `GetDlgItem` in thread function `CopyThread`

Comment: @eran code updated, please check it out.

Comment: Windows have thread affinity and I wonder if your problem is related to that.

Comment: @eran whole code posted, and you can download it directly from this [link](http://tunps.com/tmp/UsbAutoCopy.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've updated the code, the problem is clearer:

```
arg = malloc(sizeof(args));
```

means sizeof(args) are allocated. Since you typedef `args` as **a pointer** to `struct args`, it means only 4 bytes are allocated (assuming 32 bit). This is enough for the first field of the struct, but when you do:

```
arg->hWndDlg = hWndDlg;
```

you write beyond the allocated memory, on some no man's land.

To solve your problem, you should malloc(sizeof(struct args)), which is sizeof(CHAR) + sizeof(HWND), instead of sizeof(struct args*). Or, better yet, change your typedef so it's less error prone, for instance:

```
typedef struct ArgsTag {
    CHAR vol;
    HWND hWndDlg;
} Args, *ArgsPtr;
```

or so, and then use Args for the allocation, and ArgsPtr for accessing it.

Comment: @Lundin +1, I totally agree with that. I've done it above to match the OP's code, but I never do it in my code. Writing the `*` is not such big a burden, and hiding it just makes your code less readable and more error prone (as on this case).

Comment: @eran , i updated the code, but `hLog` window handle still got 0x00000000 error address and cause the memory voilation.

Comment: @tunpishuang Is the value of arg->hWndDlg correct now, namely as you set it in the message loop? From what I understand, your problem is getting a handle to a control on your main dialog window, isn't it? If so, does GetDlgItem with those arguments work on the main thread?

Comment: @eran , arg->hWndDlg isn't correct. but in message loop everything is OK. i want to get a handle to a control on main dialog as you said. GetDlgItem works on main thread (the UI thread)

Comment: @eran , `arg->hWndDlg` isn't correct. but in message loop everything is OK. i want to get a handle to a control on main dialog as you said. GetDlgItem works on main thread (the UI thread) 
in main thread the address of hWndDlg like **0x000a0436** , but in `CopyThread` hWndDlg like to be **0x65645c70** , a very big integer.

Comment: @tunpishuang So we're back to stage one then. No reason for GetDlgItem to succeed if it gets a bad value. What is CopyThread doing with `arg`? there's nothing wrong with the code you've posted, but someone has to corrupt `arg` before you use it. Also, chances are really slim, but is there by any chance a change in struct packing or alignment in your code (search for 'pack' and 'align' in the code)?

Comment: @tunpishuang If you haven't found the problem yet, it's in how you use `pvol`: you set it to point on the beginning of the `arg` struct, and then you override its content with the `strcat`. Look at the value of `arg->hWndDlg`: you say it's 0x65645c70, which as TCHARs would be "p\de", which is part of ":\dp\device.ini". I guess you wanted to point `pvol` to `temp`, didn't you?

Comment: @eran ok, frankly i have debug this code for 4 days. i commented code one line by one line. and i found the problem as you said. actually i wanted to let `pvol` pointer to a value `'\0'` just like reset its value to zero and then strcat ":\somedir\somefile.exe" or something like that. pvol is always a volume character like **A** **B** .... and at last i found `memset` just meet me need. lol. many thanks for you patient explanation and sorry for the bad grammer English.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the right vol then it means you are initialising the struct at least partially correctly. Check to ensure the HWND you copied is the same as the actual one. If you are making a modeless dialog box then the return is the HWND. If you are making a modal one then you can pass in a pointer to the struct with DialogBoxParam() which you can then initialise in WM_INITDIALOG.